# Regex match BETWEEN 2 symbols

Tags: regex

I got this regex which is not working 100%

`@+(.+? )`

If I got this text:

`@@ss@aa s`

It should match this, because I want to match everything BETWEEN `@` and  , but subsequent `@` should be ignored:

`aa`

But instead of it, it matches:

`ss@aa`

Any tips? I tried using the greedy modifier, that didn't work.

Comment: The problem is the a regex period also matches an at-sign.  To make it not match the at-sign replace ".+" with "[^@]+".

Comment: Note that ".+" also matches spaces so your original regex when applied to "@@ss@a s@b s"  would match "ss@a s@b ".

Comment: You wrote, "...I want to match everything BETWEEN `'@'` and `' '` but subsequent `@` should be ignored:". I interpreted that as meaning you wish to match `'@ss@aa'`, but you wrote that you wish to match `'aa'`. That being the case you may wish to instead write,  "...I want to match everything BETWEEN `'@'` and `' '` with no intervening `@` characters".

Comment: Should there always be a space following, or should it also match at the end of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to capture the text between the @ and ends with a space?

Try this (with space at theend):

```
@([^@]+)
```

[REGEX101 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4G3S.jpg)

Explanation:
The above regex will find @ followed by multiple characters that is not an @ and ends with space. The parethesis will capture the string between the @ and space

Link to regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/PhVOD4/1

Comment: This doesn't work if there are several spaces in the string: https://regex101.com/r/rkRkgz/1

Comment: Yes, this solution will find @ followed by multiple characters that is not an @ and ends with space. If you want the first space Cory’s answer with lookahead will do for you. The question is a bit unclear so we dont know what the author really intends. Just provided a solution that captures what he wants given the input text

Answer (score 3):

You can attempt to match the regular expression

```
(?<=@)[^@ ]*(?= )
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YkZPam/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=@)  # a positive lookbehind asserts that the match is preceded by '@'
[^@ ]*  # match zero or more characters other than '@' and a space
(?= )   # a positive lookahead asserts that a space follows the match
```

---

If regex engine supports `\K`, which resets the beginning of the match and discards all previously-matched characters, you could match

```
@\K[^@ ]*(?= )
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1GpQa6/1)

`\K` is supported by PHP, perl, Ruby, R (with `perl=TRUE`), Python (with the alternative PyPi regex module) and other languages.